# div causing errors in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting errors when div elements are present, but when I remove them (Only keep Text), NO issues.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-6 justify-content-center my-5">
      <Text style={{color: "green", fontSize: 8, textAlign: 'center'}}>Hello</Text>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

This error is located at:

> ```
>        in div (created by App)
>        in div (created by App)
>        in div (created by App)
>        in App (created by withDevTools(App))
>        in withDevTools(App)
>        in RCTView (created by View)
>        in View (created by AppContainer)
>        in RCTView (created by View)
>        in View (created by AppContainer)
>        in AppContainer
>        in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
> ```

I want to use div tags in ReactJS. How do I achieve this? I am using     React 18.2.0.

Comment: div is for the browser, not for react native app. use `View` instead

Comment: Which is it, ReactJS or ReactNative?

Answer (score 3):

In RN you don't use div, you should use View instead
check the [View documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view) here

> The most fundamental component for building a UI, View is a container that supports layout with flexbox, style, some touch handling, and accessibility controls. View maps directly to the native view equivalent on whatever platform React Native is running on, whether that is a UIView, , android.view, etc.